# How to snapshot access DB with linked tables

Tags: ms-access, backup, linked-tables

How can I make a snapshot of my data if my only access is via linked tables in access. I need monthly backups of my data.

Options:

1. Outputting to Access DB - maintains the links and therefore the data continues updating? Seems risky.
2. Creating new DB with linked tables merely imported - this would mean they don't update but is difficult
3. Exporting to Excel - looping through DoCmd.transferSpreadsheet - but this causes me errors and doesn't export all tables.

Anyone solved this issue? seems like there should be an easy answer.

Comment: Have you tried something like `SELECT * INTO local_table FROM linked_table;`?

Comment: I'd need to loop through ~30 tables and I really want to output this to a separate file to keep my linked front -end working well.

Comment: It seems like you'll need to loop through the tables anyway if "[your] only access is via linked tables in access", implying that you can't just make a copy of the back-end database every month. As for the "separate file" requirement, you could do `SELECT * INTO [;Database=C:\__tmp\archive_2015_01.accdb].sometable FROM someLinkedTable;`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it that you can't access your backend database file?

Comment: What is your BE? Is it and Access file? Or ODBC linked to SQL Server or some other server db?

Comment: We use ODBC linked to a SQL Server I do not have access to.